# Diophantine equation with prime exponents

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Prove that the equation $2^p+3^p = a^n$ has no solutions, where $p$ is a prime number and $a,n > 1$ are integers.

The only thing that I proved is that $2^p+3^p$ is divisible by $5$ or that it equals $5$ modulo $p$ (Fermat's little theorem).

Comment: The first statement holds only for odd primes. The second only for primes larger than or equal to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Since you have proved $a$ must be divisible by $5$, reduce the equation modulo $25$ and see what you can deduce.

Comment: But I found that if p is 5 or 23 2^p + 3^p is divisible by 25.

Comment: No, not $23$. Determine those integers $k$ for which $2^{1 + 2k} + 3^{1 + 2k}$ is divisible by $25$.

Comment: You are very right. I calculated with calculator when p is 23 and for that reason I thought it was no use. But when you said that 23 isn't I write the remainders by module 25 and p has to be divisible by 5 to 2^p + 3^p be divisible by 25. Because of that only p=5 works. Am I right?

Comment: @user124636 How do we know that $2^p+3^p$ is divisible by $5$ by Fermat? We only know that $2^p+3^p \equiv 5 \bmod p$ which is something else.

Comment: 2^p + 3^p = (2+3)(2^(p-1)+2^(p-2)*3+…+2*3^(p-2)+3^(p-1)) and that's how I proved that the left side of the equation is divisible by 5. By Ferma theorem I prove that the remainder of the left side of the equation when DIVIDED BY P IS 5 (THE REMAINDER).

Comment: @benh Since $p > 2$ is odd, we write $p = 2k + 1$. Then $2^p + 3^p = 2^{2k + 1} + 3^{2k+1} = 2\cdot 4^k + 3 \cdot 9^k \equiv 2(-1)^k + 3(-1)^k = 5(-1)^k \equiv 0$ mod $5$.

Comment: @user124678 I see, sorry. I somehow missed that.

Comment: @user124678 Euler's theorem shows that $2^{20} \equiv 1$ and $3^{20} \equiv 1$ modulo $25$. Therefore the sequences $2^{2k + 1}$ and $3^{2k+1}$ are periodic modulo $25$ with period dividing $10$. In fact, a direct calculation shows that their period is $10$, but $2^{2k + 1} + 3^{2k + 1}$ mod 25 is periodic with period $5$. Thus   $p$ is among $5$, $15$, $25$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the equation as:
$$\frac {2^p+3^p}{a^n}=1$$
you can use the LTE to analyse the power of $n$.

Now $a=p_1^m\cdot p_2^m\cdot ....\cdot p_j^m\cdot ....\cdot p_k^m$ and for the LTE theorem the greatest power that divides $2^p+3^p$ is:$$\upsilon(2+3)+\upsilon(p)$$
Now we analyse two cases:

$1)$ if $p_j\neq p$

The greatest power that divides $5$ is $1$ if $p_j=5$ or $0$ if $p_j\neq 5$

$2)$ if $p_j=p$

the graetest power that divides $2^p+3^p$ is $1$ if $p_j\neq 5$ and $2$ if $P_j=p=5$ but $$\frac {2^5+3^5}{5^2}\neq 1$$.

Answer (score 0):

Since one is seeking $2^p + 3^p$ as a power, and $p$ is prime, then the only prime which yields a multiple of 25 for $2^p+3^p$ is $p=5$.  But $275$ isn't a power of anything.

Any other prime yields a multiple of 5 and a non-multiple of 5.